# How to know if a dialog is dismissed in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

If the dialog is dismissed,I want to do something for my background.So I want to know if the dialog is dismissed

Comment: If you do not expect to receive any data but just want to know the dialog is gone perhaps this may help: https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/ac79d3864a96344d204d869d64fd1922

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use an `onDismissListener`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html

```
public Dialog createDialog() {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface arg0) {
            // do something
        }
    });
    return d;
}
```

If you are using a `DialogFragment` just override `onDismiss()`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss(android.content.DialogInterface)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29)

Comment: Fantastic BUT it does not get the case of the device being rotated - which kills the dialog.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JoeBlow When the device is rotated and the activity recreated `onCreate` will be called and `Bundle savedInstanceState` will not be equal to `null`. You can store any state (for example, a boolean whether the dialog was showing before the device was rotated) in `onsaveInstanceState` and reference it here.

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately `setOnDismissListener` is only supported on API 17+. Is there a way for earlier API versions?

Comment: `setOnDismissListener` has been available since API level 1 I believe. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)

Comment: Weird, Android Studio kept complaining. Thanks though.

Comment: Is there a way I can find out which dialog existed in a clean way (My activity launches different dialogs for different purposes and all are custom dialogs)?

Answer (score 6):

@Ken Wolf has a great answer to this question.

Just wanted to add that `onDismissListener` was only introduced in `API 17`. If you are trying to support something lower, you can use `onCancelListener`, which is not as good but covers cases like backButton and tapping outside of the AlertDialog.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html#onCancel(android.content.DialogInterface)

```
public Dialog createDialog() {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // do something
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the `onDismissListener` is called even when you select one of the options in the alert (Yes/No/Neutral button). For me `onCancelListener` was the best option since I needed something that tracked an explicit closing of the dialog by clicking outside the alert area.

Answer (score 0):

When dialog closed, you can use `dialog.setOnDismissListener` at the following code with the usage of an updated dialog code.

```
private void ShowDialog() {      
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(ActivityMain.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            dialog = new Dialog(ActivityMain.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.addContentView(view, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Button dialogBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
            dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();                
                }
            });
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface arg) {
                    //when dialog closed
                }
            });

    }
```