# State Machine inside Android - Stop onActivityResult breaking game while loop flow

Tags: android, switch-statement, state, state-machine

I am trying to implement a `State Machine` into my Android game (note that it is not a game that needs to be constantly redrawn with a UI as it just works using standard Android `Activity` structure). I have found this example below of how you can implement a `State Machine` with a `switch` statement:

```
main() {
    while(true) {
        collectInput(); // deal with common code for filling in keyboard queues, determining mouse positions, etc.
        preBookKeeping(); // do any other work that needs constant ticks, like updating streaming/sound/physics/networking receives, etc.
        runLogic(); // see below
        postBookKeeping(); // again any stuff that needs ticking, but would want to take into account what happened in runLogic this frame, e.g. animation/particles/networking transmit, etc 
        drawEverything(); // any actual rendering actions you need to take
    } 
}

runLogic() {
// this is where you actually have a state machine
    switch (state) {
        case WaitingForInput:
        // look at the collected input and see if any of it is actionable
        case WaitingForOpponent:
        // look at the input and warn the player that they are doing stuff that isn't going to work right now e.g. a "It's not your turn!" notification.
        // otherwise, use input to do things that might be valid when it's not the player's turn, like pan around the map.
        case etc:
        // a real game would have a ton more actual states, including transition states, start/end/options screens, etc.
    }
}
```

Whilst transitioning my game from the loop below to the `State Machine`, I am having issues. If say from this main game `Activity`, I launch another `Activity` in order to ask the player a question (happens inside `playTurn()`), I will then obviously utilise `onActivityResult()` and return the player's answer to the main game `Activity`. How should I handle the return of the player's answer and allow the code to then continue running in `playTurn()`, inside the main `playGame()` loop, without breaking the while loop flow? The only way I actually can figure out is by utilising a while loop inside `playTurn()` that simply keeps looping whilst the answer is 0 but that seems horrifically wasteful. Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

```
public void playGame() {
    initialise();
    boolean finished = false;
    while (!finished) {
        playTurn();

        // Check if there is a winner after each turn is played
        boolean winner = winner();
        if (winner) {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why starting a new Activity and not using a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), instead?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Dialogs cannot go full screen as far as I'm aware and the Activity contains a lot of content. If this is not true, please suggest otherwise.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi The code for the Activity is also quite complex.

Comment: In the page I linked, you'll find out how to set a [Dialog in FullScreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog). And also how to make a [Custom Layout Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout).

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi What do you think is the trade off of Dialog vs. Fragment for this instance? Both will mean that a new Activity doesn't need to be launched and an answer passed back.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Anyway if I use a Dialog, it still doesn't fix my issue as I would have to have an OnClickListener and then action in there, which also breaks the flow of my main game loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544819/how-to-know-if-a-dialog-is-dismissed-in-android