# how to stop scheduled timer after dialog is closed

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a scheduled timer running to show the delay in coming to school. Whenever a student arrives to the school, a custom dialog opens up with display showing the `delay in arrival : 20.0 min`. It gets incremented by `0.5min` every half a minute. My code is -

```
public void startTimer(long delay_minutes) {
    final long delay = delay_minutes;
    delay_countup = (double) delay;

    //Start the scheduled time
    departuretimer = new Timer();
    departuretimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            countup = 0.0 + delay_countup;
            Log.d("hi","Values 0" + delay_countup + countup);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
            delay_countup = delay_countup + 0.5;
            Log.d("hi","Values 1" + delay_countup);
        }
    }, 0, 30000);
}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            delay_time.setText(String.valueOf(countup) + "min");
            rootView.invalidate();
        }
    };
```

The problems are -

a) the timer runs in background for the old arrived student even when the dialog is opened for new arrived student. I mean the timer is never killed when the dialog is closed.(The dialog is closed only to confirm the arrival of the student)

b) Sometimes the textview `delay_time`displays wrong value. It shows `22.0min` and immediately `0.5min` and then again `23.0min`.

Why is this?

**EDIT 1**: 
Handling `timer cancel` after click of button in the dialog

```
private void handleClickAction() {
        dismiss();
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
}
```

**EDIT 2** :
The logs always display correct values but in the UI sometimes there is a problem. The problem is that for example -

```
delay_countup = 50.0 
countup = 50.0
Textview updates as 50.0 //This is correct

Now, 
delay_countup = 50.5 
countup = 50.5
Textview updates as 0.5 //This is incorrect. I need 50.5
```

This happens sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are never removing the first timer. So when you initialize the second timer you have two timers simultaneously trying to update the UI.

Store the timer as a member variable and check if it's initialized before starting a second one. When the dialog is closed you should `cancel()` the `Timer`.  So you should also see how to implement methods [when the dialog is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17544849/6543020) - this should call a cleanup method which `cancel()` and sets the timer to null.

```
public class DialogTest extends Dialog {

    Timer timer;
    double countup = 0;
    double initial_time = 0;

    public DialogTest(Context context){
        super(context);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        startUpCounting();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e("b", "timer stopped");
        if(timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    public void startUpCounting() {
        delay_for_student.setText("Delay in Arrival");
        rootView.invalidate();
        Log.e("b", "timer started");
        if(timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                countup = 0.0 + initial_time;
                if (countup == 0.0) {
                    onTimeHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
                } else {
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
                }
                initial_time = initial_time + 0.5;
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }



    public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.e("b", "timer: " + countup);
            delay_time.setText(String.valueOf(countup) + "min");
            rootView.invalidate();
        }
    };

    public Handler onTimeHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.e("b", "timer ---");
            delay_time.setText("-");
            rootView.invalidate();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ok I just have 1 timer and it is scheduled timer which I put in the function startUpCounting() as shown above. Currently what I did was, when dismiss() was called, the next line I give timer.cancel() but still does not work

Comment: Is the method being called? Can you include more code? Set it to null as well.

Comment: This method is being called only once in onFinish() of countdown timer and I set timer to null as well. Still not working..See my updated question

Comment: The code you posted shows it in a click method - that means it wouldn't be cancelled if the dialog is dismissed without clicking the button (such as clicking outside the dialog area)

Comment: No..handleClickAction() is called when the button is pressed. The handleClickAction() is inside onClick()

Comment: I updated my solution - but I just realized I'm using a `DialogFragment`, not a `Dialog`. I'll edit it again

Comment: Thank you :) I think this will work... Will it solve both the problems which I have mentioned in my question?

Comment: Yes the code I posted for `DialogFragment` solves both!

Comment: Ok it solved my first problem... But still sometimes there is 2nd problem. Is it because I am using 2 handlers?

Comment: The second problem is occurring because you have two instances running at the same time. I will edit my post for the full `Dialog` class. Be sure to add in your UI methods - I commented them out when I ran it, only using log.

Comment: Ok thank you... So I think I dont need onTimeHandler. Removing that would solve my problem?

Comment: You don't but I don't think it will.  The most important part is the `onStop` method. Make sure it's exactly the same. And make sure you are setting the timer variable exactly the same.

Comment: Ok can you see my EDIT2. Also my scheduletimer code in the question